# Istio prometheus federation

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio, configmap

I am using istio.1.6 and i was trying to store metrics from istio prometheus to external prometheus based on [istio best practise doc](https://istio.io/docs/ops/best-practices/observability/).But in the first step, I have to edit my configuration and add recording rules.I tried to edit the configmap of istio prometheus and added the recording rules.Edit is successful but when i try to see the rules in prometheus dashboard ,they donot appear(which i believe means the config didnot apply).I also tried to just delete the  pod and see if the new pod has new configurations but still the problem.
What am i doing wrong? Any suggestions and answers is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to configure federation as mentioned in prometheus [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/#configuring-federation)?

Comment: Well that's the second step in federation.First is to add recording rules in istio prometheus.That is not working.

Comment: Then from istio side I would say it might be lack of [service entry](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/). Or problem with strict mtls which is enabled by default since istio 1.5.0, you could try to change it from strict to permissive and check if it works then.

Comment: Do you know where to put the recording rules exactly?ie the first step mentioned in the documentation?I tried to put it in istio prometheus.I havent enabled mtls.

Comment: As I said, since istio 1.5.0 mtls its enabled by [default](https://istio.io/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5/upgrade-notes/#automatic-mutual-tls). I´m not sure where to put Recording rules, probably in prometheus configmap, atleast as far as i checked [here](https://github.com/askmeegs/istiobyexample/blob/888a7b5c573c9ba6bf2c0e046e44bf4f8d8d2506/content/blog/prometheus/configmap.yaml), there is all prometheus configuration.

Comment: @jt97 solved it.It was my mistake.I added the rules in the configmap but didnot  mention it in the prometheus.yaml inside the configmap.Thanks for the response

Comment: happy to hear that it works! Could you please make an answer and mark it as accepted so if someone had same problem he could find the answer here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the way I added the recording rules.I added rules in rules.yaml but forgot to mention it in rule_files field of the prometheus config file.I didn't know how to do prometheus configuration and that was the problem.

I also refered this github [example](https://github.com/jotak/istio-federated-prometheus/blob/master/istio-prometheus-cm-1.yaml)

Also check out this [post](https://medium.com/kialiproject/kiali-with-production-scale-prometheus-c53ddfa20570) on prometheus federation