# istio integration with prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio

I'm using microk8s installation of K8S and have installed Istio and Prometheus using:
`microk8s enable prometheus`
and
`microk8s enable istio`

I have also successfuly added the builtin prometheus and grafana of istio following the [doc](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/prometheus/#option-1-quick-start). Howeve, now I have two separate prometheus and grafana in my cluster 1. the one I installed using microk8s and 2. the one installed from istio.

I want to follow the instruction of option 2 in the doc to add extra configuration to the microk8s prometheus following [Istio prometheus federation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036776/istio-prometheus-federation), [this site](https://istiobyexample.dev/prometheus/). But I don't know where exactly I should add the configs mentioned in the link to my existing microk8s prometheus. Here is the list of all objects in my monitroing namespace (microk8s prometheus):

```
(base) ➜  inference kubectl get all -n monitoring                                                                   
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE
pod/alertmanager-main-0                    2/2     Running   2 (6h3m ago)   19h
pod/prometheus-adapter-59df95d9f5-c6v99    1/1     Running   1 (6h3m ago)   19h
pod/prometheus-operator-7775c66ccf-bl7qj   2/2     Running   2 (6h3m ago)   19h
pod/blackbox-exporter-55c457d5fb-rg9x4     3/3     Running   3 (6h3m ago)   19h
pod/node-exporter-sx4fw                    2/2     Running   2 (6h3m ago)   19h
pod/kube-state-metrics-76f6cb7996-xmpss    3/3     Running   3 (6h3m ago)   19h
pod/grafana-6dd5b5f65-l44p4                1/1     Running   1 (6h3m ago)   19h
pod/prometheus-adapter-59df95d9f5-ksp85    1/1     Running   1 (6h3m ago)   19h
pod/prometheus-k8s-0                       2/2     Running   3 (6h3m ago)   19h

NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/prometheus-operator     ClusterIP   None             <none>        8443/TCP                     19h
service/alertmanager-main       ClusterIP   10.152.183.234   <none>        9093/TCP                     19h
service/blackbox-exporter       ClusterIP   10.152.183.176   <none>        9115/TCP,19115/TCP           19h
service/kube-state-metrics      ClusterIP   None             <none>        8443/TCP,9443/TCP            19h
service/node-exporter           ClusterIP   None             <none>        9100/TCP                     19h
service/prometheus-adapter      ClusterIP   10.152.183.240   <none>        443/TCP                      19h
service/alertmanager-operated   ClusterIP   None             <none>        9093/TCP,9094/TCP,9094/UDP   19h
service/prometheus-operated     ClusterIP   None             <none>        9090/TCP                     19h
service/prometheus-k8s          NodePort    10.152.183.52    <none>        9090:30090/TCP               19h
service/grafana                 NodePort    10.152.183.15    <none>        3000:30300/TCP               19h

NAME                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
daemonset.apps/node-exporter   1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   19h

NAME                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/prometheus-operator   1/1     1            1           19h
deployment.apps/blackbox-exporter     1/1     1            1           19h
deployment.apps/kube-state-metrics    1/1     1            1           19h
deployment.apps/grafana               1/1     1            1           19h
deployment.apps/prometheus-adapter    2/2     2            2           19h

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/prometheus-operator-7775c66ccf   1         1         1       19h
replicaset.apps/blackbox-exporter-55c457d5fb     1         1         1       19h
replicaset.apps/kube-state-metrics-76f6cb7996    1         1         1       19h
replicaset.apps/grafana-6dd5b5f65                1         1         1       19h
replicaset.apps/prometheus-adapter-59df95d9f5    2         2         2       19h

NAME                                 READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/alertmanager-main   1/1     19h
statefulset.apps/prometheus-k8s      1/1     19h
(base) ➜  inference
```

Which one should I edit? I'm very confused here.